# Representation equivalent lattices

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, algebraic-groups

Suppose $G$ is a  absolutely almost simple algebraic groups over a number field $K$. Let $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$ be two lattices in $G(K)$. Then $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$ are said to be representation equivalent if $L^2(\Gamma_1\backslash G) \cong L^2(\Gamma_2\backslash G) $ as $G$-spaces.

Question is, do we have analogue of this notion for Zariski dense subgroups $\Gamma_i$ which need not be lattices? Also, if one of the $\Gamma_i$'s is discrete then is it true that the other must also be discrete if at all one has representation equivalence between them?

Comment: The paper by C.S.Rajan, Bhagwat and Pisolkar (see the link http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3194011) has references and some related material. As to your other question, if $\Gamma _2$ is Zariski dense but not discrete, then $L^2(\Gamma _2\backslash G)$ does not make sense.